# Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part in column "ColumnName" of recursive query "CTE"

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, string-concatenation, recursive-cte

Trying to replicate Concatenation of multiple rows into one string-->https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/t-sql-programming/concatenating-row-values-in-transact-sql/#Toc205129485

here is the query:

```
WITH CTE (id, CodeList, Code, Length)
AS (SELECT CAST(d.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Id,
           CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS CodeList,
           CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Code,
           0 AS Length
    FROM Letters d
        INNER JOIN Cat c
            ON c.ID = Cat_Sub
    GROUP BY d.id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CAST(dp.id AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Id,
          CAST(
           CAST(CodeList AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                + CASE
                      WHEN CAST(Length AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = CAST('0' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) THEN
                          CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                      ELSE
                          CAST(', ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                  END 
                 ?????+ CAST(cp.Code AS NVARCHAR(MAX))?????? 
                  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
                  ) AS CodeList,


           CAST(c.Code AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Code,
           c.Length + 1
    FROM CTE c
        INNER JOIN Letters dp
            ON c.id= dp.id
        INNER JOIN Cat cp
            ON cp.ID = dp.id
    WHERE cp.Code > c.Code
   )
SELECT *
FROM CTE;
```

> Msg 240, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Types don't match between the
>   anchor and the recursive part in column "CodeList" of recursive query
>   "CTE".

I know this is a very often asked question but I can't get from where I get my error.
After testing I discovered that it comes when I add a piece of code in between question marks.
It has been casted but it still gives an error

Comment: why don't You try to add this line between question marks to each of case statements? CAST('' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) + CAST(cp.Code AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) ... ?

Comment: Why do you need to cast Length to NVARCHAR(MAX) to check for = 0 ?

Comment: In order to see that the string not empty

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have solved the problem with another logic:

```
WITH Ranked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName )  
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId,
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY CategoryId ORDER BY CategoryId ),
                         CAST( ProductName AS VARCHAR(8000) ) 
                    FROM Northwind..Products),
   AnchorRanked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName )  
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId, rnk, ProductName 
                    FROM Ranked
                   WHERE rnk = 1 ),
RecurRanked ( CategoryId, rnk, ProductName ) 
             AS ( SELECT CategoryId, rnk, ProductName 
                    FROM AnchorRanked
                   UNION ALL 
                  SELECT Ranked.CategoryId, Ranked.rnk,
                         RecurRanked.ProductName + ', ' + Ranked.ProductName
                    FROM Ranked
                   INNER JOIN RecurRanked 
                      ON Ranked.CategoryId = RecurRanked.CategoryId 
                     AND Ranked.rnk = RecurRanked.rnk + 1 )
SELECT CategoryId, MAX( ProductName ) 
      FROM RecurRanked
  GROUP BY CategoryId;
```